# Who should own subview's viewModel in MVVM design?

Tags: swift, mvvm

I am using SwiftUI to create a MVVM application. For a single view, I know that `View` owns `ViewModel`, `ViewModels` owns `Model`, and nothing more. However, things become complicated when it comes to multiple views:

`ViewB` and an array `[ViewC]` are subviews of `ViewA`, and the requirement is: When user touches something in `ViewA`, then `ViewB` and some `ViewC` should change.

So my questions are:

- Does `View` owns (has strong reference) its `ViewModel`?
- Does parent `View` owns (has strong reference) its subviews?
- Does parent `ViewModel` owns (has strong reference) its subviews' viewModels?

As for this specific situation, the questions become:

- Does `ViewB` and `ViewC` has strong references to its `ViewModel`?
- Does `ViewA` has strong references to `ViewB` and `[ViewC]`?
- Does `ViewAModel` has strong references to `ViewBModel` and `[ViewCModel]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does View owns (has strong reference) its ViewModel?

Yes (assuming we talk about reference-type ViewModel)

> Does parent View owns (has strong reference) its subviews?

No. SwiftUI view are value-type (struct), so no references at all.

> Does parent ViewModel owns (has strong reference) its subviews' viewModels?

It can, if there is such need. It looks appropriate to have views hierarchy as presentation of ViewModel hierarchy. Moreover taking into account that parent view on refresh constructs all visible subviews to check if there is any changes, so depenedency injection of view model keeps this process much more light & fast.